# Rails - A server is already running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, localhost

I have a problem when I want to start my server in my terminal I do `rail s` or `rails server` and there is an error `A server is already running. Check /Users/baptiste/code/BaptisteB/my-app/tmp/pids/server.pid.`

What does it mean? And why it is present?

I delete it and when I check my `localhost:3000`. There is nothing. I have to log off my laptop and turn on it to begin to work.

How could I stop this error? Maybe I can destroy it with a command. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to run below command on your terminal and you will get pid (process id)

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000

COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    21309 user   11u  IPv4  93186      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

and then kill your ruby process by using

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

start your server again by `rails s`

Hope it helps!

Comment: kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3001 -t)

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have already started a rails server. What's possibly happened is that you started a rails server and closed that terminal window without stopping the server. Open a terminal window and run

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

that should give you a list of all the processes running with rails in its name. Then you can run the command below to kill all of them or get the pid (process id) and selectively terminate them with the second command. If you're on wi

```
killall -9 rails

kill pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$ cd # in the project folder
$ gem install shutup
$ shutup
```

If using rvm do:

```
$ cd # in the project folder
$ rvm @global do gem install shutup
$ shutup
```

Comment: are you laughing to me?